# Function to swap pointers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void) swapController:(MyViewController*)controller1 
                         with:(MyViewController*)controller2
{
    MyViewController *swap = controller2;
    controller2 = controller1;
    controller1 = swap;
}
```

Looks like this doesn't work because I'm not passing references. How to do it anyway?

Comment: Remember that the value of a pointer is an integer that represents the address of an object. When you pass that to the **swapController:with:** you are just passing the values to the function temporary variables (which is on the stack), and the swapping is done in these temporary variables. If you want to change the value of the pointer in function call, you should pass pointer to that pointer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by passing in pointers to the pointers you want to change:

```
- (void)swapController:(MyViewController**)controller1 with:(MyViewController**)controller2
{
    MyViewController* swap = *controller2;
    *controller2 = *controller1;
    *controller1 = swap;
}
```

Comment: then for `MyViewController *c1` pass to the function like `swapController:&c1` ?

Comment: @Michael: That is right, though I cannot imagine why you would want a generic instance method to swap two variables.

Comment: @Chuck: it's all about var names.

Answer (score 4):

Not looking for this as an opposing answer here, but rather to complement @Huw's answer.

On implementing his `swapController:with:` method above, I noticed some issues with ARC and with primitives. ARC will take issue if you're passing a ***strong id**** to an ***id**** ( which it will designate as ***autoreleased id*** and other fun warnings).

If you're anything like me, well, one fine day you'll be swapping pointers back and forth in objc and one of those values will be a primitive data type.

***If*** you do end up doing something like that, here's a little helper (like I said earlier) to complement the above answer:

```
 void swapObjcPointerWithC ( void** ptrA, void** ptrB ) {

     void *temp = *ptrA;
     *ptrA = *ptrB;
     *ptrB = temp;

 }

 ...
 // Later on

 id objA;
 int anInt = 10;
 swapObjcPointerWithC ( (void*)&objA, (void*)&anInt );
```

There you go. My two cents.
*Note:* also works will nil pointers apparently.